# ZooKeeper session expired in tests

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, spring-kafka, embedded-kafka

I'm using the EmbeddedKafka for testing my module with the following annotation confiugration:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:test.properties")
@EmbeddedKafka(partitions = 1,
    topics = {"topic"},
    brokerProperties = {
        "auto.create.topics.enable=${topics.autoCreate:false}",
        "delete.topic.enable=${topic.delete:true}",
        "broker.id=2"})
```

It works most of the times.

But **sometimes**, it fails in the creation of the spring context because zookeeper session times out:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext    at
>
> ...
>
> at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
>     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'embeddedKafka': Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is
>   org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$SessionExpiredException:
>   KeeperErrorCode = Session expired     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1745)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:410)
>     at
>   org.springframework.kafka.test.context.EmbeddedKafkaContextCustomizer.customizeContext(EmbeddedKafkaContextCustomizer.java:106)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader$ContextCustomizerAdapter.initialize(SpringBootContextLoader.java:320)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.applyInitializers(SpringApplication.java:649)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:373)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:127)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
>     ... 73 more Caused by:
>   **org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$SessionExpiredException:
>   KeeperErrorCode = Session expired     at
>   org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:130)
>     at
>   kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient.checkedEphemeralCreate(KafkaZkClient.scala:1631)
>     at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient.registerBroker(KafkaZkClient.scala:87)    at
>   kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:257)   at
>   kafka.utils.TestUtils$.createServer(TestUtils.scala:132)  at
>   kafka.utils.TestUtils.createServer(TestUtils.scala)   at
>   org.springframework.kafka.test.EmbeddedKafkaBroker.afterPropertiesSet(EmbeddedKafkaBroker.java:215)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1741)
>     ... 82 more**

Does someone know why would it happen? Why does it even need ZooKeeper when using an EmbeddedKafka??

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does it cause the test to fail? I had a similar problem in my tests but it was just log noise and there was another reason for the failing tests. But this problem made it difficult to find the original cause.